# Error while importing react-navigation & native-base

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, native-base, stack-navigator

I am new to react when I `import stacknavigator from react-navigation` or listitem from `native-base` .

1. Created new project on expo.
2. npm install --save react-navigation .
3. npm install .
4. npm start`enter code here`

I continuously get this error, tried the solution from GitHub repo issue number 4968 but that's not helpful, can you help, please? [unable to resolve react-navigation, module doesn't exist in module map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVfbm.png)

```js
App.js

 
{import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import LoginScreen from './Screens/LoginScreen'
import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen'
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator/>
    );
  }
}
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  LoginScreen : {screen : LoginScreen},
  HomeScreen : {screen : HomeScreen}
})
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});`

    LoginScreen.js

`
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View>
     <Text> This is login Screen </Text>
     </View>
    );
  }
}
export default LoginScreen;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using react-native, after you install a new package with `npm install`, you must run `react-native link` to update your node-modules folder.
Then, if using android and if it is needed, you can run:

```
cd android && gradlew clean
cd .. & react-native run-android
```

Also, your code presents some syntax errors in imports. Fix **;** in end lines and the **{** at line **3**.

Comment: Hi thank you for replying, I tried your solution but i am still getting the same error :(

Comment: Have you checked within node-modules folder if the react-navigation is in there? You can also check in your package.json file

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for pointing out that. I assumed by running `npm install --save react-navigation` will automatically do that job.

Answer (score 0):

Check NativeBase Docs. Installation for RN, Expo and web app are documented clearly.

Also check https://reactnativeseed.com/ for working examples